# Tensorflow - Disaccording TF METRICS (Accuracy, Precision, Recall)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new with Tensorflow and I am working with a CNN for an instrument recognition problem, using **IRMAS** dataset.

The **IRMAS** dataset has a clear **training** set, based only on singular instruments, therefore each instrument (guitar, violin, etc) has its own directory with multiple samples (*multi-classification*). The **testing** set, differently, contains polyphonic music, therefore multiple classes of instruments may appear in the same song (*multi-classification*, *multi-label*).

This is the final part of my network with the prediction and loss calculation, I am using the `Estimator API`.

```
### previous part of network is omitted

# logits layer
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=labels.shape[1])

print('Shape Logits:', logits.shape)


predictions = {
    # "classes": tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf.cast(logits, tf.float32), 1), tf.argmax(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), 1)),
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    "probabilities": tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), logits=tf.cast(logits, tf.float32), name="sigmoid_tensor")
}

# correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf.cast(logits, tf.float32), 1), tf.argmax(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), 1))

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=labels, logits=logits)

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    #optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.96)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
                              loss=loss,
                              global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss" : loss}, every_n_iter=10)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, training_hooks = [logging_hook])


eval_metric_ops = {
    "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
    labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1),
    predictions=predictions["classes"]),

    "recall": tf.metrics.recall(
    labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1),
    predictions=predictions["classes"]),

    "precision": tf.metrics.precision(
    labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1),
    predictions=predictions["classes"])
}
```

After few epochs, the training process seems to work since the loss goes down quite smoothly. However, the tensorflow metrics needed to evaluate the model does not seem to agree.

These are my results on the evaluation set (15% of the training set):

```
{'recall': 0.9989496, 'accuracy': 0.40656063, 'global_step': 1428, 'precision': 0.95004994, 'loss': 0.2432195}
```

These are the results obtained from the testing set:

```
{'recall': 0.9981618, 'accuracy': 0.26530612, 'global_step': 1428, 'precision': 0.96533334, 'loss': 0.46097097}
```

In my opinion, the accuracy value seems to be the only right, since decreases in the testing set, which is composed by polyphonic music rather than singular instruments. I don't understand why I get these results for precision and recall, they should be lower compared to the accuracy I get.

I've tried to display the FP, FN, TN and TP and they seem to be in accord with precision and recall. In fact, by computing the accuracy with them I got around 0.97 (too high for this classification problem).

I have not idea of what I am doing wrong, really appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: Why recall and precision are so high, while accuracy is really low? By computing TP, TN, FP, FN I got an higher accuracy, that does not match the one obtained by `tf.metrics.accuracy`

Comment: Can you please give us the values outputted vs class labels , that way can see if there is an issue with tf or your results, or some of the value which were predicted incorrectly

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am completely sure that is my problem and not tensorflow. For instance, if I use a softmax based approach rather than a sigmoid for a multi-label problem I got more realistic values. However, I should use the sigmoid since mine is a multi-classification/multi-label problem. I think the problem is on my `predictions` dictionary.